# Callback with Postback

Tags: c#, user-interface, callback, postback, repeater

This is a simple question. I recently created a web page with the option to performs some callback operations. Everything works great. The idea is to manipulate a table which I recreated with a HtmlTextWriter in the callback. BUT inside and outside the table I have some elements that perform postback for example a Checkbox which allows me to filter the actives elements in the table and some Edit LinkButtons inside the table. Anytime that I click on them, the page does a postback and the Looking and Feel of the page looks like the previous version before the last manipulation like it's never done anything at all. So postback it's ruining everything. How can I prevent this refreshing of the Look and Feel when I've already changed it with a callback.

Thanks.

Comment: I got it! The LinkButtons inside the table do a callback now and the elements outside the table, I changed them to perform operations with jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your code, but it is possible that putting your controls that are causing postback into an UpdatePanel would work. Putting them in an UpdatePanel will cause the postback to just affect the controls in the UpdatePanel instead of the entire page.